# How to not sync old photos from iCloud in new iPhone but keep backup enabled?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

My old iPhone 12 Pro) has ~140GB of storage (out of 256), and it is completely backed up in iCloud.
The problem is that the new iPhone 13 has less storage (128GB), so it obviously can't contain all of the data from the old one (mostly pictures).

I want the new phone to have a working backup for the new pictures, but I do not want the old photos to be downloaded.
After I started the new phone it started syncing all of the old data, including the pictures, and I had to stop the process because it reached full capacity.
Now the process is paused and the backup is not working.

Is there a way to make it work?
I can't find anything about this scenario, which is weird, I mean, there's no way to downgrade the disk space with newer phones.

Comment: Do you still have your old phone?

Comment: @nohillside Yes, I do

Comment: In case setting "Optimize Storage" on the new phone only will not work (because the restore will overwrite settings), you can set it on the old phone, do another backup and restore that one.

Comment: @nohillside Not sure what you mean with the old phone, I do not want to restore anything, the old phone still has everything on it.

Comment: Ah, had to reread your second paragraph, this isn't about restoring a new phone from an old as I initially thought. You can't have iCloud Photo Library enabled without it downloading at least low-quality versions/thumbnails of all pictures in it. But it should manage space in a smart way when "Optimize Storage" is enabled.

Comment: @nohillside That's what I thought (and hoped) will be the case, but currently the phone has 121GB of photos that were downloaded from the initial sync, even with the optimization enabled

Comment: Don't consider iCloud to be a backup of your photos. It is only a mirror. If a photo is deleted on your phone you run the risk of the delete being propagated.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths Yeah, that's exactly what I came to realize, so if that's not the solution to backup, what is? I want something that works seamlessly like icloud. And also, why do they call it "Backup Your iPhone" then?

Comment: You wrote: "I had to stop the process because it reached full capacity" – what indicated this was needed? Did the system show an error message?

Comment: @Ezekiel Yes, the sync process stopped and there was a message saying that there's not enough disk space to continue. I don't remember exactly what was written. And indeed if I look at the iPhone storage I see it's at 98% capacity.

Comment: @NitzanTomer Okay, and at that point was "Optimize Storage" enabled in Photos settings?

Comment: @Ezekiel Yes, the setting was on, and still is

Comment: @NitzanTomer Thank you, and your photos are what is taking up all the storage? What does the Photos app say if you open the first tab and scroll to the bottom (should have a sync status and a photo count)

Comment: @Ezekiel Yes, the photos take most of the storage, 121GB out of 128 (I updated the question with the right storage sizes).  In the Photos app it says: "Syncing Paused for 3,291 Items"

Comment: @NitzanTomer Have you tried restarting your phone? Optimize Storage should not download the originals in this case so maybe something that simple could fix that.

Comment: @Ezekiel Just tried, and nothing changed

Comment: An iPhone backup stored in iCloud is different to iOS Photos also storing photos in iCloud. The latter is just to sync between devices, and to store the original full size ones if you choose to only use 'optimised' versions on your iPhone (eg smaller res). The former can be used to restore your phone in the event of loss, damage etc.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths Is there a way then to change it so that it does not try to restore my phone and just keep the optimized sync of my photos?

Comment: @NitzanTomer The reason you're getting conflicting responses is your device is **already** setup the way you want it, it's just not working.

Comment: When iCloud Photos is enabled, the backup has no photos in it because they're stored in iCloud Photos - so you're already doing the thing you want where it doesn't try to restore anything except the optimized photo.

If you look in your iCloud backup info, it should show no photo data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use iCloud Photo Library you must either:

- Enable "Optimize Storage" and accept that your originals will not be on the phone
- Buy a phone with enough storage for your entire photo library

If you would like to keep "Download Originals" enabled, then you must export and delete your older photos to another system. This is easiest to do on a Mac (highest fidelity - originals or as-edited files), but can also be done from icloud.com or privacy.apple.com (least fidelity - just the original files)

---

Personally, I keep Optimize Storage enabled on my phone and Download Originals enabled on my Mac where I then back up to Time Machine, but I understand that not everyone has both devices to work with.

Comment: I do have the "Optimize iPhone Storage" setting on, but it still syncs the photos

Comment: @NitzanTomer Point of clarification, are your photos currently stored in an iCloud Backup or in iCloud Photo Library (are they visible on iCloud.com?)

Comment: The photos are indeed visible in icloud.com. I have "Sync this iPhone" enabled in the iCloud drive, and also in iCloud Photos. And "Back Up This iPhone" is also on in iCloud Backup